# OpenAPI solution for pagination for large datasets

Tags: python, sorting, openapi, openapi-generator

In a real-world scenario, I want to handle more complex sorting logic and potentially pagination for large datasets.

In this example using flask, need improve solution on this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# Sample data
items = [
   {"id": 1, "name": "Apple", "price": 2.5},
   {"id": 2, "name": "Banana", "price": 1.5},
   {"id": 3, "name": "Orange", "price": 3.0}
]

@app.route('/items', methods=['GET'])
def get_items():
   # Extract query parameter for sorting
   sort_by = request.args.get('sort_by', default=None, type=str)

   # Check if sorting is requested
   if sort_by:
       try:
           sorted_items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[sort_by])
           return json(sorted_items)
       except KeyError:
           return json({"error": "Invalid sort parameter"}), 400
   else:
       return json(items)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

We define a Flask route at /items to retrieve items.
We use the sort_by query parameter to specify the field by which to sort the items.
If the sort_by parameter is provided, we sort the items accordingly using Python's sorted() function with a lambda function as the key.
We handle potential errors if the sorting parameter is invalid.

Comment: That all looks fine. And what is your actual question?

Comment: This code does not give me actual scale. So , need more inputs on how to scale it up for 2million entries.